# How can I do a 3d animation where inbetween frames are jumping to one value to another without easing in?

Tags: transforms

I say kinda stop motion like, what I'm really looking for is a step animation where there are no middle part between two frames. The result should be an object jump cutting to another location.

Just curious if there is a simple method of making all animation like this in the dope sheet.

Comment: Something similar to this kinda  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nl7inkkqnro&index=5&list=PLtiFcD8HPjVP_snVlheoZdJELUE10TZle

Answer (score 2):

Many different ways:
If you want no interpolation between two keyframe you can set the interpolation mode to "constant" in the user preferences panel.

You can also do it after the programming: open the graph editor, select all keyframes and press T and choose constant interpolation mode.

Another way is to use the dopesheet (expecially useful if you want some keyframes to "jump" and others to have a linear or bezier ease interpolation): select the first keyframe of the "jump" section and copy it near the last keyframe (one or two frames before).

The video you posted seems to be not completely "jumping": it uses short interpolations but not constant at all. The constant mode is also very useful during the Blocking phase of the animation, for preparing the "animatic" version of the movie.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's also the [Stepped Interpolation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/graph_editor/fcurves/fmodifiers.html#stepped-interpolation) modifier. You can use it at the F-Curve level with the Graph Editor (to modify a single property curve, like the X-location for example), or also with the NLA Editor to apply a single modifier to an entire action, causing a whole character to become stop-motion-like.

The benefit of using this modifier is that you can animate with bezier curves and have the stepped inbetweens be calculated for you, saving lots of time.

Note that to use an Action modifier on the NLA Editor so your whole character has stepped motion, you will need to push your Action into the editor as a new strip. When this is done, editing the action (to modify or polish your animation keyframes further) will require that you select the Action track and hit the Tab key to enter into action editing mode. To learn more about this, study [how the NLA Editor and Actions work in Blender](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/nla/tracks.html).