# Keyframes without interpolation / Behaviour

Tags: rendering, keyframes, performance

a quick question on how keyframes / rendering an animation works within Blender.
I want to render multiple images with different settings within some materials ,different shapekeys and poses, but no movement at all. I thought the best way to archive this, is to render a x frame sequence and have drivers tap in or out with 100% on each frame. So my question is: How does Blender handle this?
For each frame, will blender first apply all keyframes and then render ? Also can I deactivate the interpolation thing, or can it happen that something is not 100% on frame 2 when i have set it 0% on frame 1 and 100% on frame 2 ?

A short answer is all i need, thanks in advance.

Also on a side note : How is Blender handling resources ? Besaid file is getting kinda large with many meshes/materials and i have experienced slower performance while doing the same tasks (like creating another mesh :D).Making other stuff invisible didn't seem to change that. Moving them to another layer seemed better (maybe that in fact is freeing all memory for those items ?).It is still very workable, but in general, if there is a way to make blender kinda ignore all the stuff i don't need right now entirely without removing it from the file, that would be great.

Thank you in advance, again. 
Have a nice time,  Aaron.

Comment: Set the interpolation to constant: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/graph_editor/fcurves/introduction.html?highlight=interpolation

Comment: Please don't ask more than one question per post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can a single Curve Interpolation Mode set to Constant?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2379/how-can-a-single-curve-interpolation-mode-set-to-constant) and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57779/how-do-i-make-the-speed-of-an-animated-object-constant-instead-of-accelerating/57783#57783 and [How do I make the f curve 'non-existent', and have simple on/off motions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55907/how-do-i-make-the-f-curve-non-existent-and-have-simple-on-off-motions/55908#55908)

Comment: Also : [How can I do a 3d animation where inbetween frames are jumping to one value to another without easing in?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78919/how-can-i-do-a-3d-animation-where-inbetween-frames-are-jumping-to-one-value-to-a/78920#78920)